# session Storage not working in device

Tags: ios, session, storage, ionic-framework

I'm keeping in session one json array, the evidence that I do in the browser function without problem but when I try to test them on devices (iOS or Android) does not hold anything, I am using AngularJS + ionic. With this function I keep everything:

```
.factory('sessionService',['$http',function($http){
 return {
     set:function(key,value){
        return sessionStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(value));
     },
     get:function(key){
        return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
     },
     destroy:function(key){
        return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
     },
  };
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use localStorage.Test if the values are overwritten or deleted after app restart on device (specially for iOS), anyway.

Comment: I worked, I had to adapt some things in treatment but solved my problem. thank you very much.